# Bluetooth LE ScanResult is returning null, but I know my peripheral is broadcasting a heart rate Service UUID (as verified by 3rd-party BLE app). Why?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm frustrated by my BLE scan returning no GATT Service UUIDs (i.e. the `scanRecord.getServiceUUIDs()` returns `null`). However, I know my heart rate peripheral is working and advertising correctly because the heart rate service is discovered (and readable) by the LightBlue app).
Here's my function in my `ScanCallback` object:

```
override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
    super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)
    // This log shows that result.mServiceUuids is null
    Log.i(TAG, "BLEDeviceManager.ScanCallback.onScanResult: ${result.toString()}")

    // TODO: handle null ScanResult
    val parcelUuids = if (result.getScanRecord() != null) result.getScanRecord()!!.getServiceUuids() else null
    if (parcelUuids == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "parcelUUids was null for scanRecord = ${result.getScanRecord()!!.toString()}")
        return
    }
    val serviceList = ArrayList<UUID>()
    for (i in parcelUuids.indices) {
        val serviceUUID = parcelUuids.get(i).getUuid()
        if (!serviceList.contains(serviceUUID))
            serviceList.add(serviceUUID)
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "Here is a list of the service UUIDs: $serviceList")
}
```

Here's the log:

> I/BLEDeviceManager: parcelUUids was null for scanRecord = ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=null, mServiceSolicitationUuids=null, mManufacturerSpecificData={}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=3, mDeviceName=blehr_sensor_1.0]

What am I doing wrong such that the `mServiceUuids` is always null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the ScanRecord you output, your device is not advertising ANY service UUID. That doesn't mean it doesn't HAVE that service....it just doesn't advertise it.

You might want to connect to it and then call discoverServices() to get the list of services it really has...

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't realize that the services were not discoverable until connected because the were not advertised. Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that your device advertises invalid data. If so, Android will return an empty list of services even if the invalid data was in an unrelated field.

So analyze the advertisement data and check it for the UUID you are looking for. Once you understand what's going on, you can parse the data yourself.

(The below code is Java instead of Kotlin. But Android Studio should convert it automatically.)

```
@Override
public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
    super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
    ScanRecord scanRecord = result.getScanRecord();
    byte[] advertisementData = scanRecord.getBytes();
    Log.i(TAG, "advertisement data: " + bytesToHex(advertisementData));
}

private static final char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```